# My PC has started shutting down on its own

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, hardware-failure, shutdown

In the past month I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to W10. It all went well but now my PC has been shutting down on it's own.

In my honest opinion, it can't be hardware since it has been happening since the upgrade, but there's something going wrong and causes my PC to shut down at random (Some times it would shut down after an hour of running, now it shut down before the computer even booted in W10).

The temps seem fine (and of course can't be temps since I just mentioned that it shut down before the boot), HHD seem fine and I haven't checked the CPU (Intel Xeon E3 1226 V3), the Rams (cant remember the model but are 2 sticks of 4x4gigs) etc. My PSU is Thermaltake Smart Se 630w and hadn't caused me any problems when I was on W8.1 .

Is there any problem with my W10?

Could it be my hardware and could the problem coming after the upgrade be coincidence? How could I check it?

Comment: Open `Event Viewer` and check some of the first message that was saved after reboot. I think there are any `Kernel-Power` errors which includes error codes of last fail.

Comment: Is it shutting down "correctly" by Windows or just turns off like power loss? In the last case it is more lickely a hardware (PSU or motherboard, etc) failure, the first one could be a software problem.

Comment: @Nick It's like a power loss. It's immediate, and restarts on its own.

Comment: @VaggelisD If you do nothing, then does the computer restart immediately, or after a while? Is your BIOS set to power-on or stay off after a power loss? (If it's set to power-on, can you change it to "stay off" and see if that changes the computer's behavior?)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It restarts after 5 seconds on it's own. I will take a look at the BIOS a bit later since I am doing some work at the moment. I was told to unplug and plug the cables again, and check from the BIOS if it can recognize the RAM sticks, the CPU etc. Should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest just checking the BIOS first, and see if it's set to power on after a power loss event. (Most modern BIOSes have such settings.) If it is, set it to remain powered off, and see if the problem goes away (as in, the computer stays off). I get the feeling that you are tripping a protection circuit in the power supply; when that protection automatically resets after a moment, if the BIOS is set to power on after power loss, the motherboard will detect that as power returning. If that is indeed the case, then you likely need a new PSU. If so, Windows 10 is most likely a coincidence.